# How to get video size/format/access from gdrive shareable link

Tags: javascript, video

There is this feature in my app where user can add videos using gdrive shareable link. I uploaded the video in gdrive and then created a shareable link. Pasted that link in the upload form and then video gets added. I need to validate 3 things -

1. format must be mp4
2. file access is provided or not
3. file size is more than 25mb

Following is my code -

```
var link = videoUrl;
if (link.indexOf('drive') != -1) {
    var gdrive = link.replace('/view?usp=sharing', '').replace('open?id=', 'uc?export=download&id=').replace('file/d/', 'uc?export=download&id=').replace('/edit?usp=sharing', '');
    videoUrl = gdrive;
}
var videoelement = createVideoElement(videoUrl);

createVideoElement = function(url) {
    var element = document.createElement('video');
    element.src = url;
    element.width = '400';
    element.height = '200';
    element.controls = true;
    element.autoplay = 'autoplay';
    return element;
};
```

Sample Video Shareable which I am trying to add - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B31psA0C98iFNl9ScWRESTBxalk

I have worked with fileupload earlier and I am familiar how to validate the uploaded file size. But here, since it is gdrive link couldn't an idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the video size by looking at the video metadata - you don't need to download the full video for this:

```js
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.preload = 'metadata';
video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  alert("metadata loaded")
  var duration = video.duration;
  alert("duration is " + duration)
}
```

Comment: `video.duration` is the time duration? or video size